# Finding elements of $K[[x]]\setminus K[x]_{(x)}$.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $K$ be a field. We have that the elements of $K[x]_{(x)}$ are of the form $\frac{f}{g}$ for some $f,g\in K[x]$
such that $g(0)\neq 0$. Since the units of $K[[x]]$ are the elements not vanishing at $0$, we may understand 
$\frac{f}{g}$ as the element $fg^{-1}$ of $K[[x]]$. It follows that $K[x]_{(x)}\subset K[[x]]$. Is there an easy way to determine if 
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i x^i\in K[[x]]$ belongs to $K[x]_{(x)}$ or not?

Comment: Why you think about this question?is there any background?

Comment: Just to note that $k[[x]]$ is the $(x)$-adic completion of $k[x]$. Hence every element of $k[[x]]$ has an approximation in $k[x]$. I am not so certain what you mean by "easy".

Comment: Yes there is an easy characterization : elements of $K[x]_{(x)}$ correspond to formal series $\sum a_i x^i$ such that $(a_i)$ satisfies some linear recurrence relation after a certain rank. This is almost the same proof of the periodicity of the decimals for $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ : if $\sum a_i x^i=\frac{P}{Q}\in K[x]_{(x)}$, write $P=Q\times\sum a_i x^i$. Since $P$ has only finite number of coefficients, after the rank $\deg P$, the $(a_i)$ will satisfies some linear recurrence relation $0=\sum_{k=0}^{q} b_k a_{i+k}$ where the $b_k$ are the coefficients of $Q$.

Comment: Conversely, if the $(a_i)$ satisfies a recurrence relation $\sum_{k=0}^q b_k a_{i+k}$ (at least after a given rank), then putting $Q=\sum_{k=0}^q b_k x^i$, you will have that $Q \sum a_i$ is a polynomial $P$. Moreover, if $Q(0)=0$ then so is $P$ so you can divide by a power of $x$ to assume that $Q(0)\neq 0$. Hence $\sum a_i x^i=\frac P Q\in K[x]_{(x)}$.

Comment: From this, you can easily construct an element of $K[[x]]$ which is not in $K[x]_{(x)}$ : take the sequence $a_k$ where $a_k=1$ iff $k$ is a square and $0$ elsewhere. There will be arbitrary long sequence of 0 in $(a_k)$ so that $(a_k)$ does not satisfies a recurrence relation.